# how to give validation to this dynamically created hidden field

Tags: jquery, html

how to give validation like required and pattern to these hidden fields.its not working in chrome.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12" id="taxes">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <label for="add_tax" class="control-label col-md-3">Tax Component</label>
    <button id="b1" class="btn btn-info add_tax col-md-9 col-sm-12" type="button">Add</button>
    <div class="template_tax  col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="controls" id="profs">
        <div id="field_tax" class="form-group input-append col-md-12">
          <select class="select form-control col-md-5" id="field1" name="tax1">
            <option value="">select Tax</option>
            <option value="project">project1</option>
          </select>
          <input autocomplete="off" class="input form-control col-md-5" id="field2" name="tax2" type="text" placeholder="tax %" data-items="8" pattern="\d+(\.\d*)||(\.\d*)?" title="(Must be a numeric or decimal value)" />
          <button class="remove_tax btn btn-danger form-control col-md-2" type="button">X</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jquery file used for the above html code.

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".template_tax:first").hide(); //hide template

        /* Add new item based on hidden template */
        $(".add_tax").click(function() {
          var newItem = $(".template_tax:first").clone();
          newItem.find("select").attr("id", "field_tax" + ($(".template_tax").length + 0)); //rewrite id's to avoid duplicates
          newItem.find("input").attr("id", "field_tax" + ($(".template_tax").length + 0)); //rewrite id's to avoid duplicates
          newItem.show(); //show clone of template
          $(".template_tax:last").after(newItem);
          bindRemove();
        });

        /* Bind remove function to last added button*/
        function bindRemove() {
            $(".remove_tax:last").click(function(e) {
            if ($(".remove_tax").length > 1)
              $(this).parents(".template_tax").remove();
          });
        }

        /* Execute bind-function at startup */
        bindRemove();
});
```

Comment: did you try jquery validation jquery.validate.min.js?

Comment: @Kamalkrishna Sahu where is your validation code?

Comment: i just added require and pattern in html i didn't used jquery @Santhucool

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. You say 'dynamically created' fields... you've tagged this with `jquery`

Comment: now you can see my jquery file Mr. White

Comment: validation in Chrome seems to be triggered when you hit the submit button. That button is missing in your sample

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to validation on your html tags (example: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp ). The answer is: you shouldn't. Client side validation like these are merely a guideline, and an attacker can easily circumvent them. And since these inputs are hidden no normal user will find them. Just make sure to validate on the server side!

If you really want to do this, you can do `$('#my_id').attr('required', true)`, or similar for pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Write it in your script, this is one type of validation. you can change it as per your requirement

```
$("#field2").keydown(function (e) {
if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
                    // Allow: Ctrl+A, Command+A
                (e.keyCode == 65 && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) ||
                    // Allow: home, end, left, right, down, up
                (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
                    // let it happen, don't do anything
                    return;
                }
                // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
                if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a `<input type="submit"/>` element in a `<form>` element to trigger the validation. Also, just add `required="required"` to the `input` element to make it mandatory.

```
<form action="?" method="get">
  <div class="form-group col-md-12" id="taxes">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <label for="add_tax" class="control-label col-md-3">Tax Component</label>
      <button id="b1" class="btn btn-info add_tax col-md-9 col-sm-12" type="button">Add</button>
      <div class="template_tax  col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="controls" id="profs">
          <div id="field_tax" class="form-group input-append col-md-12">
            <select class="select form-control col-md-5" id="field1" name="tax1">
              <option value="">select Tax</option>
              <option value="project">project1</option>
            </select>
            <input autocomplete="off" required="required" class="input form-control col-md-5" id="field2" name="tax2" type="text" placeholder="tax %" data-items="8" pattern="\d+(\.\d*)||(\.\d*)?" title="(Must be a numeric or decimal value)" />
            <button class="remove_tax btn btn-danger form-control col-md-2" type="button">X</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

check out this [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/04ewgd01/)

**UPDATE**

To prevent the Chrome error about an invalid form control, remove the `required="required"` part from the inital input field and add it using javascript:

```
newItem.find("input").prop("required", "required"); // make it a mandatory field
```

Check this [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/04ewgd01/1/)

Comment: in chrome it is showing error " An invalid form control with name='tax1' is not focusable.  " @Mr. White

Comment: why should the `field_tax` be hidden at first? If you remove `$(".template_tax:first").hide();` it works

Comment: Or, have the inital field non-mandatory and add the `required` part using javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/04ewgd01/1/ . See my updated answer...